# selenium 2 - C# SelectElement not selecting in Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the following code in C# to select a value in a dropdown list:

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("element"))).SelectByIndex(2);
```

This works with Firefox and IE8 but not with Chrome, nothing gets selected. Are there any know issues with SelectElement? Any alternatives to get it to work in Chrome?

I'm using the standalone server 2.0rc3 and Chrome 12

Comment: Would you be able to perform the find By.Id() instead?  I found the Firefox driver seems to be the most stable, and Chrome tends to have these occasional inconsistencies (perhaps exacerbated by their constant updates?)

Comment: the element only has a name, I tried XPath instead and still no dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the Chrome driver. The IWebElement.Select() and .Toggle() methods were deprecated in 2.0RC3, requiring you to use .Click() instead. The SelectElement support class was updated to handle this change; however, the ChromeDriver.exe (which is built and provide by the Chromium team) has yet to catch up. So using IWebElement.Click() on an  element doesn't yet work in Chrome.

Comment: This has been fixed in the 7/7/2011 release of chrome driver, hurray!
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/downloads/list

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this problem, I solved it by clicking on the element and sending the keys to select the value, so something like:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("element")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Name("element")).SendKeys("some value");
```